# How to update each row with incrementing count

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar field in my MySQL table and I want to update each value for a column called as `day` with incrementing value of 1

so 1st row would be 'day1' and second row would be 'day2'

Can anyone suggest something in this regard

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, you do this using user-defined variables.  These are implicitly defined by putting an '@' sign before variable name.  So, to incrementally set the value of a column to "day 1", "day 2", etc., you could do something like this:

```
BEGIN
    SET @x := 0;
    UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT('day ', @x := @x + 1);
END
```

Since there ';', you need to change the default delimiter from ';'.  I'm going to assume you're using command line MySQL utility.  You would enter the above like this:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> BEGIN
mysql>   SET @x := 0;
mysql>   UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT('day ', @x := @x + 1);
mysql> END
mysql> //
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html for details

Comment: Do I have to surround your code with something. Because right now it is giving me Syntax error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to update a little bit, I mean it was not working without actually creating a procedure and then executing it. But still you answer did most of the trick. Upvoted.